# Limit Sum of Values and Subtraction

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to implement a code that would reference values from another worksheet in the current document, sum those values and limit the addition to a value of 90 to then substract them to a set of values stored in another column. I keep getting an error for property assigned

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim Filament As Integer
Dim Remaining As Integer
Dim sumRemaning As Integer
a = 1
b = 1
'Add loop here for Filament
For b = 1 To 10
Filament = Cells(Target.Row("A"))
sumRemaining = 0
    Do While sumRemaining <= 90
        a = a + 1
        Remaining = Worksheets("Printer Log").Cells(a, 2)
        sumRemaining = sumRemaining + Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Remaining)
    Loop
Cells(b, 3).Value = Filament - sumRemaining
Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect from the next line `Filament = Cells(Target.Row("A"))`? Also from `Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Remaining)`...

Comment: From the way you worded your question I can't tell what values you want to subtract from where. Can you please be more clear about which sheet you are referencing and where the data comes from? Pictures with sample data would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring at this line:

```
Filament = Cells(Target.Row("A"))
```

The reason why is because you were attempting to assign a Range to an integer; these are two different data types. If you wanted to get the sum of all values in the A column you could use the Worksheet SUM function (shown below).

The function below will:

- get all the values in the A column from Sheet1 (iValue1)
- get the value in cell A2 from Sheet2 (iValue2)
- subtract iValue2 from iValue1
- takes the result and outputs it to cell B3 on Sheet1.

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If (Cells(3, 2).Value = "") Then 'cell C2. 'when you use .Cell you reference the column first, THEN the row. You can substitute a string value for the column integer but it is less effecient.
          Dim iValue1 As Integer 'do not use a capital letter at the beginning of an integer variable. By convention variables begin with a lowercase letter.
          Dim iValue2 As Integer
          Dim iResult As Integer

          iValue1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) 'you need to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum here
          If (iValue1 > 90) Then iValue1 = 90 'make sure sum of A column is not greater than 90. You don't need a loop to do this.
          iValue2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Value
          iResult = (iValue1 - iValue2)
          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Value2 = iResult
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Note that there is an evaluation condition at the beginning of the Sub; this keeps the Sub from running repeatedly. You can do it like this and click "clear contents" on cell B3 (output cell) to make it run again. Alternatively you can create a button on your sheet to trigger this action (recommended) instead of using the Worksheet_Change Sub.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. If you want to subtract values from one sheet instead of the other you can just swap the variables around.

Comment: Thank you, the reason to behind using a loop was to just limit the summation for up to 90, then reset the value to 0 and start the summation again. Since the values in column A would quickly surpass 90.